# automatically import typescript JS modules in VSCODE

Tags: javascript

I want to import JS modules, so I am using

```
 import @ from "module";
```

But it automatically imports micorosoft/typescript/3.5. and gives me the error "TS 6133".

I just want to use a JS module in a JS file.

```
import under from "underscore";   <- but TS 6133 error and not import node_modules folder
import morgan from "morgan";      <- but TS 6133 error and not import node_modules folder
```

Before installation, `express --save` can find, but afterwards it cannot.